# Bash Script to check for host

Tags: bash

I have a complicated script request that I am trying to figure out. Basically, I need a script that will check for certain conditions and depending on the outcome will run certain commands.

So, I need it to check if $hostip is up and running. If it is running, I need it to check and see if $domain has same IP address as $domainip. If they match, script then ends. If they don't match, I need to run command "shutdown $hostip". Now, if it fails to find $domain, ie internet is down, then I need it to sleep for 6 hours and then try again. I want it to try 3 times and if still can't find domain after 18 hours, then run "shutdown $hostip".

The goal above is to shutdown a server if the domain does not match the set IP or the internet is disconnected for 18 hours.

I also need script to check the other side of things as well. So, if $hostip is not online, but $domain and $domainip do match, then power on server.

These are my variables I have so far.

```
domain=google.com
domainip=216.58.194.46
hostip=192.168.1.1

gatewayip=$(ping -q -c 1 -t 1 $domain | grep PING | sed -e "s/).*//" | sed -e "s/.*(//")
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are two parts to this.

First, you need to check if the hosts is up. You can do this with `ping` as you have done:

```sh
ping -q -c 1 "$domain" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which will set its exit code to true or false as expected if the host is up or down. Note I've removed the `-t` option as it was causing the `ping` to fail.

Second, you need to check that `$domain` resolves to `$domainip`. You can do this with several tools - `host` is straightforward:

```sh
host -t a $domain | grep -q "$domain has address $domainip"
```

Putting that together you get something like:

```sh
domain=google.com
domainip=216.58.194.46
hostip=192.168.1.1

for i in {1..3}; do
    sleep 6h

    if ping -q -c 1 "$domain" 2>/dev/null; then
        exit 0
    fi

    if host -t a $domain | grep -q "$domain has address $domainip"; then
        exit 0
    fi
done

shutdown $hostip
```